# How to read socket response after writing to ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, sockets

I am using `Socket`to send a task from one server to another like so:

```
private boolean sendRequest(String address, int port) {
    boolean requestComplete = false;
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject("task_to_complete");

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String msg = (String)ois.readObject();
        if(msg.equals("complete")){
            requestComplete = true;
        }
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestComplete;
}
```

The second server receives the task like so:

```
while (true) {

    // wait for connection
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("New connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());

    // retrieve request from server
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    String msg = (String) ois.readObject();

    switch (msg) {
    case "task_to_complete":
        // do task 1
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Task " + msg + " complete.");

    // send a message back to client with the result of the task it
    // requested
    PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.print("complete");
    ois.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

But I get the error

> java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)

when I attempt to read the message "complete" from the first server:
`ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up your protocol because

- the server writes the response with `PrintWriter.print("completed")`
- the client reads it with `readObject()`

I put a [working demo on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd23c9027242f6a5b13c)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String msg = in.readLine();

if(msg.equals("complete")){
        requestComplete = true;
    }
```

it worked for me in a similar situation

Comment: This gives me a `NullPointerException` for  "msg".